# 'RiakBucket' object has no attribute 'new_binary'

Tags: python, riak

As I'm trying to store a PNG image file into my riakBucket. As per https://riak-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/1.5-stable/tutorial.html documentation described here actually using riakBucketObject.new_binary().

But when I'm trying to do this over my system, this error is pop-up:

My python script is :

```
>>> import riak
>>> myClient = riak.RiakClient(pb_port=8087, protocol='pbc')
>>> photo_bucket = myClient.bucket('photo-bucket')
>>> file_data = open('/home/kamli/Pictures/Store3.png','rb').read()
>>> key = photo_bucket.new_binary('myphoto', data=file_data, content_type='image/png')
```

But error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'RiakBucket' object has no attribute 'new_binary'
```

System Configuration:

```
Python version - 2.7.6
Riak Version - 2.2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riak 2.2 has changed since 1.5 and the current method to get a new RiakObject from a bucket is simply using `RiakBucket.new()` or `RiakBucket.new_from_file()`. The documentation can be found on their [readthedocs website](http://riak-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.0/bucket.html#bucket-objects). Look for the version switcher near the bottom to look at documentation for each major release.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what **Aaron3468** said, I would like to mention that the Riak Python Client's version does not match Riak's version. The client is versioned according to semver and the latest release is [available here](https://github.com/basho/riak-python-client/releases/latest).

Please use the [latest documentation](http://riak-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).